# Is there a reasonable way to do a regression analysis without knowing the correlations between correlated regressors?

Tags: regression, logistic, correlation, missing-data

I have several datasets, each with the same response variable but with different regressors. Unfortunately, I do not know the correlation between the regressors from the different datasets, but have reason to believe that there is a correlation. Is there a reasonable way to combine the response variable and all the regressors into a single regression or other coherent analysis without knowing the correlation between the regressors?

To specify my question a bit more, I can give the following simplified example:

- One of the datasets shows the effect of household income on the probability of owning a coffee machine.
- Another dataset shows the effect of household size on the probability of owning a coffee machine.

If I want to know how likely it is to find a coffee machine in a household with a given income level and a given size, I cannot simply multiply the probabilities, since the independence assumption is unrealistic. Bigger households probably have higher income on average. How can I merge the data sets without knowing the correlation between household income and household size?

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Does something keep you from calculating the correlations between your predictors?

Comment: The problem is that I need to merge the data sets to calculate the correlations, but to merge them correctly I think that I already need to know the correlations. To clarify my problem I have added a simplified example to my question. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What measures the probability of owning a coffee machine? Do you have observations that go income, size, owns a coffee machine (yes/no)?

Comment: Yes, I have one data set with observations that go income, owns coffee machine (yes/no), and a separate data set with observations that go size, owns coffee machine (yes/no), and more data sets of in the same format. Unfortunately I don't have income, size and other characteristics for the same observations since the data comes from different sources. Is there any way to combine the data anyways?

Comment: Then this is a missing data problem. Once you DEs with that, the logistic regression (random forest, SVM, whatever) to predict coffee maker ownership is straightforward. I suggest tagging this to reflect that. Also check out the Data Science Stack to see if they’re more active about the topic. I don’t see much of that here, and you might be more likely to get an answer over there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I have tagged "missing-data" and I will check out the Data Science Stack. One last question: What do you mean with "Once you DEs with that"?

Comment: I mean that I’m typing on my phone. “Once you deal with that...”

Comment: Thank you once again!

Comment: As a heads up, “once you deal with that” might make it sound like it’s fairly easy. It will not be not, but if you can solve it, then you’ve got fairly straightforward data to run through a classifier like logistic regression.